# Xamarin Forms Stacklayout StackOrientation.Horizontal

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

When i set StackOrientation.Horizontal for stacklayout and setting 5 labels it displays properly.

[image]

But when the number of labels count is increased labels text size reduced and all labels are aligned for available width.

[image]

How to display full text for all labels also move label to next line if the labels count exceeds?

Answer (score 3):

`StackLayout` with `Horizontal` `orientation` will only use "one line".

For that case you should use a [GridLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gridlayout/) or [WrapLayout](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/WrapLayout.cs) (From [Xlabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs)).

In alternative you could use a `StackLayout` with `Horizontal orientation` and each `Child` is a `StackLayout` with `Vertical orientation`.

Comment: The below lines will not work in this case "In alternative you could a StackLayout with Horizontal orientation and each Child is a StackLayout with Vertical orientation.". WrapLayout suggested first by @misho is exact soln. Thanks u guys.

Comment: Why ("StackLayout with Horizontal orientation and each Child is a StackLayout with Vertical orientation") it will not work in your opinion?

Comment: StackLayout with Horizontal orientation wont allow you to move labels to next line. We have to go for WrapLayout for this

Comment: You din't understand what i'm saying. For example you could use a StackLayout with Horizontal orientation with 6 childs. Each child is another StackLayout with Vertical orientation. Its almost like a grid. But yes, WrapLayout is the way to go. I've already said that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `WrapLayout` instead:

```
    var layout = new WrapLayout {
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                    Padding = new Thickness (0, padding, 0, padding)
                };
    layout.Children.Add (item);
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin 3.0 introduced [`FlexLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout) for exactly this use-case.  It's based on CSS Flexboxes.